# Assert status in Laravel Dusk

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I have a test which verify status. It should be 200

When I run this

```
public function testBasicTest()
{
    $response = $this->json('GET', '/');
    $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

It pass but when I add url: /clients
always status 404

```
public function testBasicTest()
{
    $response = $this->json('GET', '/clients');
    $response->assertStatus(200);
}

Error: 
Expected status code 200 but received 404.
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

Comment: show your route please

Comment: `php artisan route:clear` tried this ?

Comment: @SandeepSudhakaran my url in .env?

Comment: show your `/clients` route

Comment: can you share that specific URL('/clients') code?

Comment: Bro, 404 error is not found error.  we have to see where you define your `/clients` route code?

Comment: I am pretty sure that /clients does not exist anywhere. Share with us your routing files.

Comment: @pr1nc3 my file is below

Comment: You have not set your /clients route anywhere. You need to define your route before access it. Do you have a controller designed for clients?

Answer (score 0):

change your `route.php` like below. I added `/clients' route in ti.

```
<?php


   Route::get('/', function () {
      return view('welcome');

   });

   Route::get('/clients', function () {
      return view('welcome');

   });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');

});
```